# ssh issue of docker in redhat 6.5

Tags: ssh, docker

I enable docker in redhat 6.5 by following the guide of centos6 and create a redhat 6.5 base image. The 6.5 imange can run well in the container but while I enable sshd in the image, the sshd always terminate my ssh client immediately once login successfully.

I save the image and load into my ubuntu 14.04.1 docker and then the redhat6.5 sshd works well. So I think the redhat 6.5 sshd image shall be ok. And then, I save my ubuntu ssh image and load into the redhat 6.5 host, the ubuntu sshd also works well in the container of redhat 6.5. So I really do not understand why my redhat 6.5 sshd image can not work well in the container of redhat 6.5.

My Docker information:

```
[root@c111bc2n10e1 ~]# docker info
Containers: 4
Images: 32
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:3-1572873-pool
 Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 2501.9 Mb
 Data Space Total: 102400.0 Mb
 Metadata Space Used: 3.1 Mb
 Metadata Space Total: 2048.0 Mb
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
Username: apollos
Registry: [https://index.docker.io/v1/]
```

SSH Server:

```
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 7
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 7
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
```

SSH Client:

```
debug1: PAM: reinitializing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
Connection to 9.114.46.152 closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the workaround and there is two opitons:
1) Change UsePAM no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

or

2) Comment session    required     pam_loginuid.so in /etc/pam.d/sshd

But I do not understand the root cause. Who can help on it?

Comment: You saved me! Exact same issue.
Centos6.5 is officially unsupported for Docker. Upgrade to Centos7 if you can (I can't).